# Why can't my Sandox Refresh Script INSERT Accounts?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I finally got a sandbox refresh script written, tested, and deployed to prod yesterday. But when I actually a sandbox and have it run on the sandbox copy, I don't actually get the records it's supposed to create. Debug log shows this error:
EXCEPTION_THROWN|[67]|System.TypeException: DML operation INSERT not allowed on Account

The beginning part of my script works fine, inserts three Chatter groups and a Task. But then when it starts the part that creates Accounts, Contacts, etc, it fails.

I found a reference to a known issue that says it was closed in Winter '16. (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008epFAAQ). No other references that seem relevant.

Anyone know what's up?
(I'm not pasting in the code because it compiles, gets 100% test coverage, deploys to Prod, and can be executed in Execute Anonymous, so I think I'm safe in saying the only problem is with it running in sandbox refresh context.)

```
global class SandboxRefreshScript implements SandboxPostCopy {
global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
    // Change value of Alias below to the Alias of user who should own the group
    // ensuring that it is unique among your users
    List<User> groupOwner = [SELECT Id, Username FROM User WHERE Alias = 'MKolo'];
    Id grpOwnerId = groupOwner[0].Id;

    // Create a Chatter Group for Payment Pipeline Changes
    List<CollaborationGroup> groups = new List<CollaborationGroup>();

    CollaborationGroup pipeline = new CollaborationGroup(
        CollaborationType = 'Public',
        Description = 'Group for showing changes to the cashflow pipeline. ',
        Name = 'Payment Pipeline Changes - sandbox',
        OwnerId = grpOwnerId
    );
    groups.add(pipeline);

    //Create another Chatter Group for All Spark
    CollaborationGroup allSpark = new CollaborationGroup(
        CollaborationType = 'Public',
        Description = 'All Spark group. ',
        Name = 'All Spark - sandbox',
        OwnerId = grpOwnerId
    );
    groups.add(allSpark);

    //Create another Chatter Group for Hiring Notifications
    CollaborationGroup hiringNotifications = new CollaborationGroup(
        CollaborationType = 'Private',
        Description = 'Hiring Notifications group. ',
        Name = 'Hiring Notifications - sandbox',
        OwnerId = grpOwnerId
    );
    groups.add(hiringNotifications);

    insert groups;


    //Create a Task for yesterday (so it's immediately overdue) that
    //reminds to update Process Builders to use the new Chatter Groups.
    Task newTask = new Task(
        Subject = 'Fix Process Builders',
        ActivityDate = Date.today()-1,
        OwnerId = grpOwnerId
    );
    insert newTask;

    StarWarsTestDataUtil.createJediStudents();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.createCampaignHierarchy();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.createNextYrCampaignHierarchy();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.createStarWarsCompaniesWithMentors();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.createStarWarsRecruitCamp();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.createStarWarsPrograms();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.putMentorsOnCampaign();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.putStudentsOnCampaign();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.putProgramOnCatEnts();
    StarWarsTestDataUtil.putMentorships();

}
```

}

Comment: A *sample* version of the code would still be useful. I'd be willing to ask my boss if we can deploy a harmless sample file, maybe get a repro, engage premier support, that sort of deal.

Comment: Code coming, below. (You won't be able to use it directly because it's so dependent on our custom objects and record types.)

Comment: BTW- no need for you to engage Support. I have actually opened a case. But I wanted to also ask here in case someone knew something I am not finding....

Comment: Awesome. Love the data factory class. I think this should be obvious enough that anyone who cares to try to repro this should be able to do so. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: It's been several days since I opened a Premier Support case and I'm not too impressed. They wrote back that "The SandboxPostCopy interface runs under the context of the automated process user." and that I should edit that user's (or profile's) permissions. But that's not possible.

Comment: Am I going down the wrong path in thinking that part of the use for a sandbox refresh script is to create dummy data to work against? To me, that would seem one of the main uses!

Comment: I have two guesses: you're getting a MIXED_DML_ERROR disguised as a TypeException, or for some reason you can only create "Setup" objects in the initial script. I believe you should be able to move all the "non-Setup" object calls to a @future/queueable/batchable method to bypass this.

Comment: I can't disagree, but certainly the documentation implies that you can create records, not just Setup objects. It's right there in the comments of the example test class: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm

Comment: Well, we're about to have to go through this problem ourselves, so if we get caught up on it, we'll use premier support.

Comment: I'm a week in with Premier Support and they seem clueless. The first thing they did was point me to those very instructions, which didn't answer the problem. Then they said the problem was with Automated Process User and I should edit it. (Can't.) Now they're "investigating further."

Comment: @sfdcfox New update: Premier Support is still mostly baffled. Their latest suggestion does, in fact, involve editing the Automated Process User profile, which I'm very skeptical about. They said "To workaround the issue, at least one of RecordTypes for each entity must be associated with Automatic Process profile. 

Login as the customer's admin account 
Move to /setup/ui/profilerecordtypeedit.jsp?id=00e300000012jCi&tid=Account 
Add —Master— then Save "  Then do this also for Campaign and Contact. If I have to do that kind of thing, the problem isn't me, it's sandbox refresh scripts.

Comment: Hello both, did you guys solve this problem? I am currently working on a PostRefresh script and I am able to insert Account / Contact / Lead but it is not inserting any CustomObject records that I want. Is Future / Queuable the way to go?